# How to suppress StyleCop Warning SA1649

Tags: c#, stylecop

I am trying to suppress two occurences of the SA1649 error in StyleCop.

According to the [documentation](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1649.html) the suppression attribute looks like the attribute below

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1649:FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
```

However, I cannot figure out what element I should apply the attribute to. If I put the attribute on the first element of the file (the IClassFactory Interface), I get the following error:

> SA1649 : CSharp.Documentation : The file attribute in the file
>   header's copyright tag must contain the name of the first type in the
>   file and can be any of these:
>   "IClassFactory"   C:(...)COMHelper.cs

Can that error be suppressed? What element should it be applied to?

Comment: Which version of stylecop are you using?

Comment: Hope this answer will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796073/issue-with-global-asax-cs-file-and-stylecop-rule-sa1649

Comment: You have to place the SuppressMessage on top of your interface. Can you show us your header of the interface

Comment: Mug4n If I place the suppress message at the top of the file, I get an error stating that Attributes cannot be applied to namespace. (because the first non-comment element is the namespace declaration

Answer (score 11):

Use a namespace level suppression:

```
[module: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1649:FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName", Justification = "Reviewed.")]

namespace MyNamespace
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suppress attributes should be placed on the class or interface declaration. This should be done in each cs file that you don't want this rule to be applied to.

However, if you want to suppress this for all your cs files in your project then you should consider disabling this rule all together in the settings. That way you don't have a suppress rule declaration on every class file.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, if I put it on the first item, I still get the style cop error.

Answer (score 0):

Chris' answer works, but to add to it you may have to suppress the file header rule too.

```
[module: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1649:FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
[module: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1633:FileMustHaveHeader", Justification = "Reviewed.")]

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="FileName.cs" company="Company">
//     Copyright (c) Company. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// <author>n00bz</author>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace TestNamespace
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="FileName.cs" company="Company">
//     Copyright (c) Company. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// <author>n00bz</author>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[module: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1649:FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName", Justification = "Reviewed.")]

namespace TestNamespace
{
}
```